# Android OnClickListener - IDE not implementing interface

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have signed up for an Android course on Edx.

I was just trying to follow the lecturer, and implement the same on my IDE.

At one point, I don't see the android studio giving the suggestion **make Mainactivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener** interface. Any idea?

That was clearly on the lecturer's video. I have posted the screenshots for the same.

Lecture:

[image: Lecture's Video]

My IDE:

[image: My IDE]

Comment: working with the same api?

Comment: Yes, Same api only. I manually implemented the interface. It worked. Just wanted to know why it occurs